# Unable to set connection password for IBM DB2 Warehouse on cloud

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

Getting the following error while trying to set the new password:

> Current password must be provided and be valid when setting a new password.

Since it asks for old password too, I am providing the Bluemix password as the old password. Unable to find a was to set the password in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the current password in the service credentials section in Bluemix.  E.g.

[image]

Attribution: http://support.datascientistworkbench.com/knowledgebase/articles/826020-getting-credentials-to-access-a-dashdb-db2-wareho

Comment: Thanks [Chris Snow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1033422/chris-snow) ! I checked "Service credentials" earlier, but since my account is new, and didn't have any default credentials, I tried to add one. The new credential pop-up asked for a json (I missed the fact that it is optional) and retreated from there and started searching for the format of the json which I couldn't find.

After seeing your answer, I proceeded without the json, and the credentials got created successfully. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You're welcome.  Can you please upvote and accept the answer if this worked for you?

Comment: Yes, I was about to do that, before which I got stuck finding how to refer you in the comment using the @ sign. Later used the link to mention your name. Let me know if this is the best way to reference a user in the comment, since I am learning to use StackOverflow, thanks in Advance :)